# Invalid regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to match my pattern with an address on java.

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9,\\.\']";
if(!address.matches(regex)) {
  //do something
}
```

Basically, I'm hoping to detect all special characters except for `,`, `.`, `'`.
With the code above, my address

> 4700 Keele Street, North York, ON

enters the if condition when it should not. Why is this happening ? 
Also how do you escape a special character ? Shouldn't it be `\$`? Eclipse IDE prompts an error stating

> "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones
>   are \b \t \n \f \r \” \' \ )"

when I do `\$` or `\^`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you need to escape most characters inside of a set. As already mentioned, you'll want to include a space and capture 1 or more of them with a '+':

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9,.' ]+";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
[a-zA-z0-9,'\\.\s]
```

You will also want to match spaces. Your expression is not including spaces, thus the address is not matching.

Answer (score 2):

A few errors in your pattern:

- you'll need to be able to match a space char, which is not in your allowed char list.
- you need to append a * or + to allow for a sequence of chars  - right now you're just asking to match *1 occurrence* of an element in the list.

So you want something like `[a-zA-Z0-9\\ ,]` along with whatever other escape chars you want to allow for.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the java doc for matches(). It will tell you that the whole string must be matched by the regex to return true. You just want to check if certain characters **occur** in the string. Therefore, you should use find(). The matches() method is superficial, it can always be replaced by find() when one writes "^regex$"

Answer (score 0):

`matches` detects if the whole address string matches the expression. And your expression can only be matched by a single character. Add a `+` at the end of your regexp to match one or several of the accepted characters.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Changed from *erroneous-pythonical* to *correctus-javonian* ...

A solution to the problem is to find just one invalid character. If: `[a-zA-Z0-9,\\.' ]` matches a valid char then: `[^a-zA-Z0-9,\\.' ]` matches an invalid character. If we can find one of these, then the string is invalid - otherwise the whole string is valid. Here's a tested script:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Test string with no invalid characters.";
        // Match just one non-valid character.
        String re = "[^a-zA-Z0-9,\\.' ]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid char found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No invalid char found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right question?  This one is tagged `java`, not `python`.

Comment: @Alan: You're right. D'oh! Back to the (Java) drawing board... (and Thanks!)